# Models in Ruby Rhodes basic questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rhodes

I'm fresh to Rhodes and don't have any experience with RoR.

I created a new model in my application:
rhogen model CoffeeKind name,description,vendor,picture

I would like to:

1. add a new property ("sizes")
2. reference another model from within this one ("vendor" referencing CoffeeVendor)
3. import various coffee kinds from json

I've got experience with Python / Django / Google App Engine, but not with Ruby / RoR.

How do I perform above tasks? Or where can I look for help? I tried googling and checking out documentation but found nothing :/

Help! :)

(I'm adding ruby on rails tag to this because I heard that it's similar to Rhodes)

Comment: Try asking in http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile and if you get an answer there then please enter it here.

Comment: thanks - I asked there as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I posted on the group:

The app generator ("rhogen" or "rhodes" command) is a "once only" thing, as it is with Rails and Django scaffolding. After initial generation if you want to add new attributes,just edit your forms to have that new attributes. It is property bag model so there is no need to create a database column or explicit modify the model

Comment: Oh, so obvious! This is the way I like it :)

Comment: it doesn't seem to work this way though.. i added a new property into the edit view and once i run an app and try to perform an update an error appears:

I 11/04/2010 10:37:44:593 b02d1000                  APP| Params: {"id"=>"58001192106057", "coffeekind"=>{"name"=>"Starbuks Latte", "description"=>"Mniam Mniam", "mgamount"=>"100", "picture"=>"", "test"=>"", "size"=>"complete"}}

I 11/04/2010 10:37:44:594 b02d1000                  APP| update_attributes Exception: #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments>

I 11/04/2010 10:37:44:595                  APP| App error: wrong number of arguments